# c# datatable/datagrid to List<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I'm pulling data from excel into a `datatable` and then to a `datagrid`. The data is in a format similar to;

```
"Time","Dist","speed","susp","rpm"
"0.000","0","235","29","13550"
"0.005","1","240","28.5","13560"
"0.010","2","245","28","13570"
"0.015","3","250","27.5","13580"
"0.020","4","255","27","13590"
"0.025","5","260","26.5","13600"
"0.030","6","265","26","13610"
```

However, the number of columns I have and the names of them are unknown in advance and will change from dataset to dataset.

The data is pulled in on a button click event (WPF);

```
    private void databtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

            var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

            if (browsefile == true)
            {
                datafilepath.Text = openfile.FileName;

                ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();

                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

                application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

                IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(datafilepath.Text);

                IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                DataTable dt = worksheet.ExportDataTable(worksheet.UsedRange, ExcelExportDataTableOptions.ColumnNames);

                DG.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i put each of these columns into individual lists of values, where the name of the list is given by the column header?

I will then use those to plot x,y charts; (time,rpm) or (distance,rpm) - I can do this, but i can't seem to iterate through the values in a specified column in the `datatable` or `datagrid`.

I am new to c# and programming in general, sorry if this is elementary and thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the lists in a `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> dict = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[c]).ToList());
```

This is a LINQ query, so you have to add `using System.Linq`.

Output:

```
foreach (var kv in dict)
   Console.WriteLine($"Column: {kv.Key}, All values: {String.Join(",", kv.Value)}");
```

Comment: Thank you, i will need to read more on the using dictionaries. Is there a way to return the contents of a specific column through a foreach loop or similair? Just thinking about getting the data into an x,y dataseries.. Thanks again

Comment: Sure, you get the list via ColumnName: List<object> values = dict["ColumnName"];

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Tim.. Last bit, i promise! Could i nest these dictionaries? So i would end up with a dictionary of dictionaries of lists... if that makes sense? I will have multiples dictionaries of lists, each one will have the same headers.. would this cause a problem when I'm getting the columns from the different dictionaries if they are nested within another dictionary? Thanks again